# Tivoli scheduler: Finding applications NOT dependent on a given application

Tags: mainframe, tivoli

I have a daily plan with 426 elements on it. Now I need to delete them in a way that ensures that none of them are run.

They "ought" to all be defined with a predecessor dependency on the "BATCHSTART" element. However, when I search for the successors of BATCHSTART the list only contains 410 elements. Conclusion: Of the 426 elements one is BATCHSTART, leaving 15 elements that are not defined as dependent on BATCHSTART.

So... short of manually comparing the lists, is there a way to find them?

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's not clear why you want to find jobs not dependent on the batchstart if you just want to delete them.

Comment: I want to find them in order to delete them. If they are not dependent on batchstart, they will be dependent on "something else", most likely something dependent on batchstart. So I need to investigate everything not dependent on batchstart to understand the proper order to delete them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done via the menus, but if you ask your operator nicely she or he might tell you the names of the tables that store the various applications and dependencies. Then you "only" have to wrote some clever code that generates the dependency graph and teases out your answers.

No, I'm not done...